# Do I have to use ContinueWith with HttpClient?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

when calling rest services using the System.Net.Http.HttpClient i have code like

```
var response = client.GetAsync("api/MyController").Result;
if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
...
```

is that proper or should i be doing

```
client.GetAsync("api/MyController").ContinueWith(task => { var response = task.Result; ...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much safer to do the second.  There are a variety of scenarios where the first option can cause a deadlock.